# Consistent & accepted style(s) for hyphenating a shade of color used as an adjective for hair?

Tags: adjectives, hyphenation, editing, colors

I'm helping edit a friend's book. Generally, I'm confident with my edits, yet one thing keeps nagging me. I'd appreciate expert guidance.

In the book, some characters have shades of *brown hair*, e.g.:

> - "… his shoulder-length, light brown hair …"
> - "… her long, dark brown hair …"

On the one hand, when I come across "*light brown hair*", I want to change it to "*light-brown hair*". My thinking: the "*light*" in "*light brown hair*" could be misunderstood as modifying the hair—as in, hair that is neither thick nor heavy (as in "*light, brown hair*"). If a reader were to briefly consider "*light brown hair*", they'd probably guess correctly that "*light*" modifies the brown, not the hair. Yet, I want to eliminate potential speed bumps.

On the other hand, when I come across "*dark brown hair*", it doesn't strike me as needing a hyphen. My thinking: "*dark*" tends only to describe the color of the hair, and no other characteristic (hair doesn't have a personality, so it wouldn't be dark in that sense). Since disambiguation seems unnecessary, hyphenating as "*dark-brown hair*" feels odd. I don't want to introduce any speed bumps.

I also value consistency. Hence, my problem. Is there an accepted approach? Thank you.

Comment: Use a hyphen when you are concerned about ambiguity. And remember what Emerson said about "a foolish consistency."

Comment: @Robusto Yes, I understand that, in general. Rather, I'm wondering if my concern itself is valid, or misplaced. I don't want to do it *my* way just because I feel good about it, but in a way that most readers will find natural. If there's a standard style, I'll happily adopt it in lieu of my intuition.

Comment: Since it is ultimately a stylistic issue, what other way would people expect you to do it than "your" way?

Comment: @Robusto Case 1: "light brown hair", "dark brown hair" (never). Case 2: "light-brown hair", "dark brown hair" (some). Case 3: "light-brown hair", "dark-brown hair" (always).

Comment: The OED attests these color words involving “brown”: *brown-green, brown-haired, brownish, brownish-black, brownish-crimson,
brownish-green, brownish-grey, brownish-red, brownish-white,
brownish-yellow, brown-red, browny-green, golden-brown, **light-brown**,
mid-brown, nut-brown, orange-brown, orangey-brown, purplish-brown,
reddish-brown, ruddy-brown, yellow-brown, yellowish-brown*.

Comment: Oops, there are like [**scaddidoodles** more where those came from](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16866130#16866130).  Caveat lector.

Answer (score 2):

The general tendency (which is not the same as "an accepted approach") that I've observed in publishing over the past 30 years is toward less hyphenation of stacked adjectives, especially when one of the adjectives essentially modifies another.

If two words possess equal force as modifiers (as is the case with *blue-gray* in the phrase "blue-gray gnatcatcher"), it makes sense to reflect the balance between the two words by hyphenating them when they appear in combination. But if one adjective dominates the other (as is arguably the case with, say, "bluish gray clouds," where the main color of the cloud is gray but that color is tinged with blue), I don't see what you gain by including the hyphen between *bluish* and *gray*.

You can apply a similar analysis to "light brown hair" and "dark brown hair": The dominant adjective in both cases is *brown*, with *dark* or *light* modifying that color. Under the circumstances, it makes perfect (and consistent) sense to render the two phrases without hyphens.

As for your concern that readers might misread "light brown hair" as meaning hair that is both lightweight and brown, the absence of a comma after *light* signals to readers that you aren't using *light* in the sense of "lightweight"; after all, *lightweight* would modify *hair*, not *brown*, so you'd want to isolate it from *brown* as clearly as possible to indicate that it referred directly to *hair*.

None of this is graven in stone, of course. You can find lots of published instances where stacked adjectives are variously hyphenated, unhyphenated, commaed, and even slashed to serve the taste of the author, editor, or publisher. And as Robusto notes in a comment beneath your question, the whole issue is ultimately a matter of style anyway—and style rules tend to be will-o'-the-wisps.

Still, if you're looking for an approach that aims to produce results that are generally consistent and fairly rational, you could do worse than to base your hyphenation of stacked adjectives on whether the adjectives represent coequal merged qualities (as in "blue-gray gnatcatcher") or whether one adjective simply modifies the other (as in "bluish gray clouds").